# F# return ICollection

Tags: f#, icollection

I'm working with a library created in C#. I've been working on porting some code to F# but must use quite a few underlying types from the C# lib.

One piece of code needs to calculate a list of values and assign it to a public field/property in the class. The field is a C# class that contains two ICollection.

My F# code works fine and needs to return an F# Seq/List.

I tried the following code snippets which each produce errors.

- Return type of F# member is a type called recoveryList with type Recoveries list
- Public field in class that is a class itself containing two ICollection objects

  ```
  this.field.Collection1 = recoveries
  ```

This gives the error Expected to have type ICollection but has type Recoveries list

```
this.field.Collection1 = new ResizeArray<Recoveries>()
```

Gives the error expected type ICollection but is ResizeArray

```
this.field.Collection1 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Recoveries>()
```

Same error as above - expected ICollection but type is List

Any ideas? These operations seem valid from a C# point of view and List/ResizeArray implements ICollection so... I am confused how to assign the value.

I could change the type of the underlying C# library, but this might have other implications.

Thanks

Comment: Jack's answer is right, but additionally note that `=` in F# is for testing equality; you need to use `<-` for assignment.

Comment: not for initalizing objects, this works fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F# doesn't do implicit casting like C#. So even though `System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>` implements the `ICollection` interface, you can't *directly* set some `ICollection`-typed property to an instance of `System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>`.

The fix is easy though -- all you need to do is add an explicit upcast to `ICollection` to your `ResizeArray<'T>` or `System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>` before assigning it:

```
// Make sure to add an 'open' declaration for System.Collections.Generic
this.field.Collection1 = (recoveries :> ICollection)
```

or

```
this.field.Collection1 = (ResizeArray<Recoveries>() :> ICollection)
```

Comment: If you're feeling lazy you can probably use `_` instead of `ICollection` and let the compiler infer it, or use the `upcast` keyword instead.

Comment: good answer this, thanks. Actually i really like the way F# doesn't auto cast anything