# Casting XmlMessageFormatter to IMessageFormatter

Tags: f#, msmq, c#-to-f#

I am trying to set the message formatter for a message in F#. In C# I can have:

```
    foreach (System.Messaging.Message message in messages)
    {
         message.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new String[] { "System.String,mscorlib" });
        string body = message.Body.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(body);
    }
```

which works just fine. I now want to do the same thing in F# and have:

```
let mList = messageQueue.GetAllMessages()
let xt = [| "System.String,mscorlib" |]
for m in mList do
    m.Formatter =   XmlMessageFormatter(xt)
```

which causes this error at compile time:

Error   2   This expression was expected to have type
    IMessageFormatter
but here has type
    XmlMessageFormatter

I suspect I am missing a basic concept in F#. What am I doing wrong?

--EDIT--
latkin's answer worked perfectly. Just in case anyone else is interested, here is the full working program in F#:

```
open System.Messaging

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    let messageQueue = new MessageQueue(".\private$\Twitter")
    messageQueue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll();
    let mList = messageQueue.GetAllMessages()
    let xt = [| "System.String,mscorlib" |]
    for m in mList do
        m.Formatter <-  XmlMessageFormatter(xt)
        printfn "%s " (m.Body.ToString())
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are assigning a mutable value, the operator is `<-`, not `=`.  In F# `=` is only used for initial bindings, otherwise it's used as the Boolean equality operator (like C-family `==`).  Some docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx).

You want

```
let mList = messageQueue.GetAllMessages()
let xt = [| "System.String,mscorlib" |]
for m in mList do
    m.Formatter <- XmlMessageFormatter(xt)
```

No casting is needed in this case.

The error comes up because the compiler thinks you are trying to compare a `IMessageFormatter` to a `XmlMessageFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

F# doesn't have implicit casts like C# does, so it doesn't automatically upcast your `XmlMessageFormatter` to the `IMessageFormatter` used by the `Formatter` property.

There was a similar question a couple of days ago with more information about this:
[F# return ICollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912548/f-return-icollection)

Comment: That's a common bug, but it's not the issue in this case.