# Defining a type with a property that is an interface

Tags: f#

I am looking for functional equivalence for the following C# code:

```cs
public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
```

I have been up and down SO and MSDN, to no avail.  Is there a different construct for properties other than this:

```
let mutable dogID = 0

member public self.DogID
    with get() = dogID
    and set(value) = dogID <- value
```

Comment: What would you expect the initial value to be? Your sample code is fine, you just need to use an `ICollection<Dog>` rather than `0` (which is an `Int`) for the initializer.

Comment: I don't know what the initial value will be be.  It will just implement ICollection.

Comment: If someone creates an instance of your class and retrieves the `Dogs` property before setting it, what value should they get?

Answer (score 3):

You can use auto properties:

```
member val Dogs = List<Dog>() with get,set
```

Comment: But not a List, I need a ICollection.  Compiler says "Invalid use of an interface type" when I replace List with ICollection

Comment: Add a cast to be explicit:   :> ICollection

Comment: I mainly use auto properties like this when implementing a C# defined interface.

Answer (score 2):

OK, Apparently I need to SO (the verb) even better.  I found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912548/f-return-icollection) which led me to this:

```
let mutable dogs = List<DOG>() :> ICollection<DOG> 


member public self.Dogs
    with get() = dogs
    and set(value) = dogs <- value
```

Thanks to Dave for pointing me at the explicit class.  Also, Genesh, I think that is what your question was?  Thanks for helping also.

Comment: That's not going to make the property `virtual`, if that's important to you. The documentation explains how to do that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx

Comment: You didn't ask but I'd also strongly consider whether or not that collection needs to be mutable. Mutable is a code smell in functional programming--not necessarily wrong but something to really think about. You're more likely to want to create a new object if you need to associate a different dog collection with it.

Comment: I am mapping back to an interfaces that was defined in C#.  LOL, the collection is from Entity Frameworks